# U0416-68 Trouble code in Honda Civic 2017

Tags: honda, civic

I was going to buy a Honda Civic 2017 and I did a scan of the vehicle before buying it. The scan showed following trouble code.

> U0416-68 VSA Brake Actuator Malfunction.

What could be the issue with the vehicle? Following page says it is a ECM failure. How can I diagnose it further?

https://static.nhtsa.gov/odi/rcl/2016/RCRIT-16V888-8684.pdf

Comment: I you have not purchased yet, I would pass on this vehicle and look at others.

Answer (score 0):

From the pdf you link to, it says that water in the connector can cause one or more of the following codes as listed.

So you should check that connector for water ingress before you spend money replacing the ECM...